# How to change the policy value of a CA identity in apple keychain?

Tags: openssl, certificates

According to [this guide](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority), I made an intermediate CA, and successfully used it to sign app in Windows. However, after converted it into a Apple keychain (by [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2206/_index.html)), this CA become having an "**iChat**" policy, which cannot be used to code signing:

```
$ security find-identity -p ichat /path/to/my_keychain
Policy: iChat
  Matching identities
  1) XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "my_identity" (CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED)
     1 identities found

  Valid identities only
  1) XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "my_identity" (CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED)
     1 identities found
```

So, how to make it to have "**codesigning**" policy? Thanks for a lot!

====

Yesterday I tried some more works. After reading the *x509v3_config* manual, I modified the CA generation, and the resultant intermediate CA has following attributes:

```
$ openssl x509 -in my_cert.pem -noout -text
Certificate:
    ......
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
            ......
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
            keyid:......

        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE, pathlen: 0
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
            Code Signing
......
```

And I re-generated the keychain file:

```
$ rm my_keychain
$ certtool i my_cert.pem k=`pwd`/my_keychain r=my_private_key.pem c
```

However, the CA in keychain is still recognized to only have **iChat** policy.

Comment: By the way, if you enforce Basic Constraints on Apple's WWDR gear, then you will break Code Signing. I reported it to Apple years ago. As far as I know, they never fixed it. Here's the Open RADAR report: [Code Signing: Breaks for Device when enforcing Basic Constraints on WWDR CA](http://www.openradar.me/13856278).

Answer (score 1):

In Keychain Access.app highlight the certificate, then "Get Info" ( <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> ):

> Under "Trust" select "Code Signing" > "Always Trust"

[image]

Comment: I imported the keychain file and modified this stuff, but why the original keychain file is not modified?

Comment: Without seeing how you imported the keychain I couldn't give you an answer to that. Maybe try making a new keychain, and saving the certificate in there.

Comment: This app can import a keychain file via File => add keychain, hot key is cmd+shift+a

Comment: Also try setting "When using this certificate" to "Use Custom Settings" or "Always Trust". Usually whenever I create a code signing certificate I "override defaults" as well...

Comment: @l'L'l I made some more efforts, still not work.